# Is it possible to compute total of subreport to main report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, subreport

This is the sample layout of my crystal report...

expenses and amount are from subreport while the project name is in the main report.

Project Title:         Expenses        Amount

Name of Project1            Item1.1             0.00
                                       Item1.2              0.00
                                       Item1.3         0.00

Name of Project2            Item2.1         0.00
                                       Item2.2         0.00

**TOTAL:**                                               **0.00**

I tried using this solution: [Crystal Reports: How to pass a parameter from a subreport to the parent report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745810/crystal-reports-how-to-pass-a-parameter-from-a-subreport-to-the-parent-report) but the problem is, it only return the last group total (in this case total expenses of Name of Project2 only and expenses in Project1 is not included in the total).

Please help. Thanks! :) God bLess!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable in the main report to store the accumulating amounts you pass back from the subreports via the shared variable.

```
global numbervar mainTotal;
shared numbervar subReportAmount;
mainTotal := mainTotal + subReportAmount
```

Really, I'd recommend doing away with the subreport altogether if you can. Doing it this way is much more complicated, prone to error, and much slower than joining all your tables in the main report or using a SQL expression.

Comment: okay, i'll try this... i have to put subreports because they come from different tables and also aside from that, those project titles and expenses are under some particulars also... Thanks for help... I'll update you if this works...

Comment: @Catholicus You need to update the mainTotal variable in whatever section holds your subreport - once per expense.

Comment: Did not work? by the way can i use sql expression?! I don't know how to pass parameters on sql expression. They said it can't be done... Is there any way to do this like creating variable?

Comment: @Catholicus You cannot use report parameters in a SQL expression, no. Your question doesn't have enough detail for me to help you with that. As for a shared variable, there's no reason it should not work. I'd do a little more investigating on what's going wrong there. OR, ideally, I'd link all your tables in the main report and go with Jeremy's suggestion.

Comment: oh... my bad... got it already... i did not total it in the report, i mean i use sql expression to compute i use SELECT SUM.........

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Ryan, lose the subreport.  Use groups and running totals to give the totals that you need.  The layout would be similar to this:

```
 Report Header: <subdued> 
 Page Header:    Project Title         
 Expenses        Amount Group Header 1: Name of Project1            
 Detail:                                Item1.1         0.00 
 Detail:                                Item1.2         0.00 
 Detail:                                Item1.3         0.00
 Group Footer: <use as space between groups or add a subtotal>
 Group Header 1: Name of Project2             
 Detail:                                 Item2.1         0.00 
 Detail:                                 Item2.2         0.00 
 Group Footer: <use as space between groups or add a subtotal>
 Report Footer:   TOTAL:                                 0.00 
 Page Footer:                                           Page x of y
```