# Crystal Report set background color instead of supress subreport

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I've a Crystal Report with 2 subreports on it.

Anyone knows if it's possible to set a background color (or image) if a subreport contains 0 rows?

The subreports shows up to 5 lines of telephones numbers but if rows are 0 I need to make that zone black (or any color) to prevent others to write on it.

My other option is a new crystal with that background color and use the correct crystal report in each case.

```
VB.Net 2010 & CR 2010.
```

Thanks!

Sorry for my english. Leave me a comment if you don't understand anything !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a parameter and pass it to the subreport and then return it to the main report.  Once that's done go into the section expert, click on the section that you want the color in.  Then click on the color tab, and create a formula like:

```
if {paramField} = 0 then crRed
else crNoColor
```

if your not sure about how to create a parameter and pass it to a subreport try this link:
[Crystal Reports: How to pass a parameter from a subreport to the parent report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745810/crystal-reports-how-to-pass-a-parameter-from-a-subreport-to-the-parent-report)